# CodeIgniter : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, codeigniter

In Local Server my `Codeigniter` project is well here is no problem, but when up it to web server occurs **Internal Server Error**

My .htaccess

```
# index file can be index.php, home.php, default.php etc.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# condition with escaping special chars
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

And all directory permission is set at **755**.

And all directory permission is set at **644**.

My site give following message in console log

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**

How can i solve this problem ?
Please some one help me.

Comment: do you use .htaccess? What URL do you use in your localhost, and what URL do you use when requesting from your server?

Comment: What version of Codeigniter are you using?

Comment: in your index.php, do you have your environment set to "production", "development", "testing" ?

Comment: it will also be helpful if you edit your original post and include your file structure., you can create one by going to this site: http://www.filestructuregenerator.com

Comment: I am using codeigniter 2.2

Comment: First make sure that your CI install is generating log files (application/logs/ is the default location), then read those logs to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to replace htaccess content with this:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|application/path_to_your_theme|images|assets|robots.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

and don't forget to replace application/path_to_your_theme